# select_related() on self for breadcrumb

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    parent = self.ForeignKey('self', null=True)

    @property
    def breadcrumb(self):
        breadcrumb = self.name
        if self.parent is not None:
            breadcrumb = "%s > %s" % (self.parent.breadcrumb, breadcrumb)
    return breadcrumb
```

I tried to add a custom Manager with select_related('parent') but obviously, it only retrieve the first parent and not the entire chain (I need to retrieve breadcrumb with a length between 1 and... as many as the user will want/need). Any advise?

Comment: I think your relation should be `parent = self.ForeignKey('self', null=True)`

Comment: What is the problem with this, you need multilevel breadcrum?

Comment: Yes my breadcrumb could have a length between something like 1 and 15... (more if needed) [question editied]

Comment: I think you should re-think about your modeling. `obj_1` could be parent of `obj_2` and `obj_2` could be parent of `obj_3` and `obj_4` at the same time. How will you follow the trace?

Comment: In my configuration, I just want to retrieve the parent which is unique. I start from the end so the trace is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: Untested code.

```
def breadcrumb(self):
    breadcrumb = self.name
    def get_next_parent(obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            return None
        if obj.parent:
            return obj.parent
        return None
    obj = self
    while get_next_parent(obj=obj):
        obj = get_next_parent(obj=obj)
        breadcrumb = '%s > %s' % (obj.name, breadcrumb)
    return breadcrumb
```

Comment: Testing right now to see if it works as expected (reducing the number of query...)

Comment: Well it does exactly the same thing, my point is: I need to retrieve with the model the breadcrumb without hitting the database each time a parent is called. (That's why I was stating the select_related stuff)

Comment: But you have more than 2 objects in the chain right?

Comment: yes! The code above (and yours also) give the expected output but I'm worried about the number of sql request made

Comment: If so, as I said before, re-think your modeling, because now if you perform a select_related you are caching only one object.

Comment: I know! I was just hoping some magic I don't know about to get the chain on the first query.. Another solution could be to calculate on save the breadcrumb, but it's a nightmare to handle all the update ><

Comment: You could connect a [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) signal to `MyModel` and update creadcrumb every time a new object us saved and perform only one query to get the current breadcrumb.

Comment: Well, a model can change parent, so I would need to update all its child. Again, so many queries :'( :'(

Comment: I guess there is no better solution. Accepting your solution now. Thks for the time you provided. #SOReadyToHelp =) Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces the same problem, you should have a look to django-mptt.
https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html

It exactly solves this problem, if the overhead is not too important for you, it's a very interesting solution.
Cheers